# CSS variables are not working / working weird

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables

I've made a button that imitates a checkbox input and wrote some js code when clicked to:

1. Change its background color by changing the css variable I set for its background color in the stylesheet.
2. Change another variable (--checked) to value 1.
    If it's clicked again then it reverts back the background color and sets (--checked) to 0.
   I've been having a variety of weird issues with the code and I got it working somehow.

Here's the code:

```
function taskDone(nodelistindex) {
  thisElement = document.getElementsByClassName('tb_checkbutton')[nodelistindex];
  readStyle = getComputedStyle(thisElement);
  vvalue = readStyle.getPropertyValue('--checked');

    console.log(vvalue + " (before)");
  if (readStyle.getPropertyValue("--checked") == 0) {
    console.log(vvalue + " in if");
    // thisElement.style.setProperty("--checked",1);
    thisElement.style = "background-color:green;";
    thisElement.style.setProperty("--checked",1);

  } else {
    console.log(vvalue + " in else");
    thisElement.style.setProperty("--checked",0);
    thisElement.style = "background-color:var(--tcolorvalue);";
  }
  console.log(vvalue+" (after)");
}
```

Here's the HTML code:

`<button style="--tcolorvalue:#CBCBCB; --checked:0" class="tb_checkbutton" onclick="taskDone(0)">`

The above code presents these issues for me:

1. The value of --checked is made to change to '1' in the if statement, it does not change to '1' but changes to '1' by the time the function runs next time, I tried to manually get the value of --checked in chrome console after its clicked but --clicked still returns '0' until its clicked again.
2. The same issue goes for the else statement where I made --checked to change to '0'. Here's the chrome console logs after I clicked it 3 times.

`0 (before)
    0 in if
    0 (after)
    1 (before)
    1 in else
    1 (after)
    0 (before)
    0 in if
    0 (after)`

3. If I comment out the 9th line and 'uncomment' the 11th line, the console log shows me this.

`0 (before)
    0 in if
    0 (after)
      (before)
      in else
      (after)
      (before)
      in if
      (after)`
Why's that?

It feels like the CSS variables are almost broken for me, I've been trying to solve the problems and each time I edit it, it brings me more issues. How can I modify the code to make it stable?

This is the console log I'm expecting:

```
0 (before)
0 in if
1 (after)

1 (before)
1 in else
0 (after)

0 (before)
0 in if
1 (after)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Oh didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to get the value using `element.style.getPropertyValue("--my-var")` rather than `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--my-var")`?

Comment: It does the same thing too..

Comment: so no one's gonna help me?

Comment: Can you add some HTML and CSS to create a working snippet?